# Pyspark list files by filtetypes in a directory

Tags: linux, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I want to list files by filetypes in a directory. The directory has .csv,.pdf etc files types and I want to list all the .csv files.

I am using the following command

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/test-output/*.csv")
```

I am expecting to get the list of all csv files in that directory.

I am getting the following error in databricks

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: /test-output/*.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a shell cell with `%sh`.  You can access DBFS and the `mnt` directory from there, too.

```
%sh
ls /dbfs/mnt/*.csv
```

Should get you a result like

```
/dbfs/mnt/temp.csv
```

`%fs` is a shortcut to `dbutils` and its access to the file system.  `dbutils` doesn't support all unix shell functions and syntax, so that's probably the issue you ran into.  Notice also how when running the `%sh` cell we access DBFS with `/dbfs/`.

Comment: Note that for `%sh` mode, `/dbfs` is an empty directory and is not tied to `dbfs:` for databricks Community Edition https://stackoverflow.com/a/68948979/1873164

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing DBFS with local file system. Where is `/mnt/test-output/*.csv`?

If you're trying to read from DBFS then it will work.

Can you try running `dbutils.fs.ls("/")` to ensure that `/mnt` exist in DBFS.

Comment: /mnt exists , I can use /mnt/test-output/*.csv to read all the files