# Can't Access /dbfs/FileStore using shell commands in databricks runtime version 7

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-community-edition

In databricks runtime version 6.6 I am able to successfully run a shell command like the following:

```
%sh ls /dbfs/FileStore/tables
```

However, in runtime version 7, this no longer works.  Is there any way to directly access /dbfs/FileStore in runtime version 7?  I need to run commands to unzip a parquet zip file in /dbfs/FileStore/tables.  This used to work in version 6.6 but databricks new "upgrade" breaks this simple core functionality.

Not sure if this matters but I am using the community edition of databricks.

Comment: what does it say the error is?

Answer (score 3):

WHen you run %sh ls `/dbfs/FileStore/tables` you can't Access `/dbfs/FileStore` using shell commands in databricks runtime version 7 because by default, the folder named `'/dbfs/FileStore' does not exists in the 'dbfs'`.

[image]

Try to upload some files in '`/dbfs/FileStore/Tables`'.

[image]

Now, try to run the same command again `%sh ls /dbfs/FileStore/tables`, now you see the results because we have upload the data into `/dbfs/FileStore/tables` folder.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: This is incorrect answer because it was not done on Community Edition that is different from Azure Databricks

Answer (score 2):

The `/dbfs` mount doesn't work on Community Edition with DBR >= 7.x - it's a known limitation.

You can workaround this limitation by working with files on the driver node and upload or download files using the `dbutils.fs.cp` command ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html)).  So your code will look as following:

```py
#write a file to local filesystem using Python I/O APIs
...
# upload file to DBFS
dbutils.fs.cp('file:/tmp/local-path', 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables/dbfs_file.txt')
```

and reading from DBFS will look as following:

```py
# copy file from DBFS to local file_system
dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/tmp/dbfs_file.txt', 'file:/tmp/local-path')
# read the file locally
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a year old, but I wanted to share other posts that I found helpful in case someone has the same question.

I found the comments in this similar question to be helpful: [How to access DBFS from shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575545/how-to-access-dbfs-from-shell). The comments in the aforementioned post, also references [Not able to cat dbfs file in databricks community edition cluster. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552922/not-able-to-cat-dbfs-file-in-databricks-community-edition-cluster-filenotfounde) which I found helpful as well.

I learned in Community Edition `ls /dbfs/FileStore/tables` is not possible because the dbfs itself is not mounted on the nodes and the feature is disabled.